# Default active dropdown menu color not changing

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, scrollspy

I want to change the background color of the active navbar list items to black. On applying my custom CSS code, the active navbar main menu items are changing their background color to black but the active navbar dropdown menu items are sticking to their default blue color(not changing to yellow color as specified in the lass css attribute). I am attaching my custom css code to clarify my problem. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

```
.carousel-inner > .item > img, .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
width: 100%;
margin: auto;
height: 850px;
}
body {
position: relative;
}
#section1 {padding-top:50px;height:500px;color: #fff; background-color: #1E88E5;}
#section2 {padding-top:50px;height:500px;color: #fff; background-color: #673ab7;}
#section3 {padding-top:50px;height:500px;color: #fff; background-color: #ff9800;}
#section41 {padding-top:50px;height:500px;color: #fff; background-color: #00bcd4;}
#section42 {padding-top:50px;height:500px;color: #fff; background-color: #009688;}
.navbar {
position:fixed;
top:0;
z-index:10;
width:100%;
opacity:0.8;
}
#nav-right li a {
background-color: green;
color: white;
opacity: 0.8;
}
#nav-right li a:hover{
background-color: black;
color: white;
}
#nav-right .active li a :not(.dropdown-menu) {
background-color: black;
color: white;
}
#drop-menu {
background-color: green;
}
#drop-menu li a:hover {
background-image:none;
}
#drop-menu .active li a {
background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: That proves why it's bad practice to use `!important`... Try to remove all your importants and give your selectors the proper order / specificity!

Comment: Yes the default color can't be changed, and if you succeeded on one browser, the style will not work on other browsers ... you can use this custom drop down lists and manipulate the style / color as you with http://www.jquery-az.com/7-customized-bootstrap-dropdown-demos-in-menus-navbar-and-tabs/

Comment: @Andreas The problem is that Bootstrap itself is one big pile of !importants. To override that, you have no choice but to use such vile practices yourself.

Comment: @Andreas I knew that it is not good to use !important. I tried a lot to customise navbar without it. But nothing was happening without it....

Comment: Instead of using `!important` in this case, wouldn't it be a better practice to just add an id to the nav and set your override style to `#myNav.navbar-right li a { ... }`?

Comment: Another option would be to add your own custom class and declare it as `.navbar-right.myClass li a { ... }`

Comment: @Chris Yongchu Thanks for the advice. Now I dont need to use !important to specify the characteristics of navbar elemants. But still the main problem of mine is not solved. The active dropdown menu links are still sticking to their default blue color while the other links are getting highlighted in black color. Can you help me with this?

Comment: If you want the active link to also be black on hover, you can use `#navbar .active li a:hover { background-color: black; }`

Comment: Thanks Chris! changing the background color instead of background image worked for me... I used                                                               #drop-menu > .active > a, #drop-menu > .active > a:hover, #drop-menu> .active > a:focus {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #17AA76, #149466);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
#drop-menu li a:hover {
 background-image:none;
    background-color:#16A170;
 }